# What is a "Tbr folder"?

Tags: windows-10

So I was just going to make a new text document.  I usually do that using Right Click > New > Text Document.  Then I realized there was a new thing: "Tbr folder".  It's also not textually formatted well.  Should I be worried?

Some extra details:
I haven't yet been able to update windows.  ...or more precisely, I *have* updated windows, probably around 40 times, but the update hasn't stuck.  Could this be related?

[image: Tbr folder]

Comment: could you run https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html and see what entries there relate to Tbr? You can search from there

Comment: @JourneymanGeek there is a result, for a file: `C:\Program Files (x86)\FarStone\TotalRecovery Pro\EFB\64\TbrFolder64.dll` -- Well, I uninstalled TotalRecovery Pro and it disappeared, thanks :D

Comment: @user2738698 you can answer your own question with the solution, then accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever it is, it is related to TotalRecovery Pro, and it goes away if you uninstall it.